# Meaning of "it's easier to AAA than it is to say BBB"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I asked a question ([Why is the L silent in “walk” but not in “bulk”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/548836/why-is-the-l-silent-in-walk-but-not-in-bulk)) and one of the commenters said to another: " **It's easier to pronounce the "L" than it is to *say* "enunciate a postvocalic lateral between a low back rounded vowel and a velar stop"** "

I don't quite understand what it means. The comment was directed at someone else.

To me, it means one of the following things:

1. It is easier to pronounce the L in "walk" than to say "enunciate a postvocalic lateral between a low back rounded vowel and a velar stop" because the quoted words are difficult and verbose.
2. It is easier to pronounce the L in "walk" than to enunciate a postvocalic lateral between a low back rounded vowel and a velar stop.

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of the comment please?

Comment: I think the comment meant (1) - the previous comment had said that pronouncing the 'l' in 'walk' was difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a joke.

"Decapitated Soul" says, "it is troublesome to enunciate a postvocalic lateral between a low back rounded vowel and a velar stop".  This means it is easier to say "waak" than "walk".

"Hot Licks" makes the joke that words like "enunciate, postvocalic, lateral" are hard words to say, and so it would also be easier to say "walk" than to say "enunciate a postvocalic lateral between a low back rounded vowel and a velar stop".